# Why callbacks in Node.js almost always take an error as their first argument?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

As the following code shows:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('somefile.txt', function(err, data) {
  if(err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  console.log(data.toString('utf8'));
});
```

I understand that we can easily catch the err info if it happens. 
But I wonder how this approach is evolved little by little. 
I would appreciate any pointer/article that would explain it well.

Comment: to do not forget the error handling? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a design choice to force programmers to not be lazy and ignore the error.

Javascript allows you to call functions with fewer or more arguments than specified. For example:

```
function foo (a,b) {
    console.log(a,b);
}
foo(100); // not an error
foo(100,200,300); // also not an error
```

This means, if the error is defined as the second parameter:

```
async(function (data,err) {/*...*/});
```

lazy programmers can simply be lazy and ignore the error by doing:

```
async(function (data) {/*...*/});
```

Of course, this doesn't prevent people form ignoring the error anyway. But at least it forces them to write down the parameter so that future programmers who maintains the code will be reminded of the missing error handler.